# Positive lookahead that (also) matches the empty string

Tags: regex, groovy, regex-lookarounds

I'm doing an internship with some Groovy code and I came across the following pattern:

`(?=(^\w)*)(\w)+(?=(^\w)*)`

It basically just finds words (contiguous collections of word characters) to sift out punctuation and such. Is there a reason to not simply use this pattern?

`\w+`

Since it's not my code I imagine that there might have been a reason for using something so ridiculously complicated, but at the same time it seems like it would be very inefficient. Is there any difference between the two? They seem to give the same results on http://regexpal.com/.

Comment: `I'm doing an internship`, shouldn't you ask this to the guys of your internship since internship is also meant to learn from the company ?

Comment: Which regular expression engine is it?

Comment: Try them out on rubular and see for yourself... http://rubular.com/r/ScDhq7dfTU

Comment: @HamZa: As an intern, I'd try to find out myself very hard before questioning someone else's code.

Comment: @krlmlr `I'd try to find out myself` and **very hard** on top of that != ask it on SO ...

Comment: According to http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions, Groovy uses Java regular expressions.

Comment: The `(^\w)*` doesn't make any sense any way (not even outside of a lookaround). Neither does a lookahead in front of `(\w)+`. I suppose this pattern is just not well thought through.

Comment: @m.buettner Outside of lookahead, this could make sense, if MULTILINE mode is active, couldn't it?

Comment: I guess someone just found out about lookaround and decided to try it out. In production code...

Comment: @LarsNoschinski no, because the `\w` cannot match the line break that would have to precede every matching position of `^`.

Comment: [regex1](http://regex101.com/r/tB9gD4) == [regex2](http://regex101.com/r/bH8xJ6). I could only imagine the lookahead is used to capture the first character in a line.

Comment: The second positive lookahead test will always fail here!

Comment: First pattern seems to pick first and last character of first word and last character of rest of the words. So both pattern isn't similar.

Comment: @fge the point is that it will not fail, but can only match by using `0` repetitions of `(^\w)`

Comment: @Lots of people:
The person who wrote the code is no longer at the company. I see asking on SO as trying very hard to not mess up the code.
Judging by the rest of the code it's not really surprising that he was a bit incompetent and didn't really think this regex through (or understand it).
It's not a multiline thing because this is applied to elements of an array produced by .split().
Thanks everyone, this has been sorted. A much more sophisticated approach to the overall problem was required anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to *why not use just `\w+`* is [capturing groups](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+5+-+Capturing+regex+groups), this doesn't explain any possible subtlety or logic in the regex though.

The (optional) prefix and suffix strings are partially captured for possible later use, and as noted by  *m.buettner*  `^\w` is quite likely a meant to be `[^\w]`, meaning the second final group never matches (though there might be cases with multi-line input, see [Pattern Matching Flags](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Documenting+Regular+Expressions+in+Groovy#DocumentingRegularExpressionsinGroovy-PatternMatchFlags), I can't see one myself, since `\w+` won't match and consume and end of line).

The use of both `(?=)` and `*` indicates that perhaps the author was not quite familiar with regexs, typically you use *look arounds* to constrain (which `*` effectively undoes here), or to optimise matching.

A polite approach might be assume that the regex was being "tweaked" during development, and has been left with some unneeded subpatterns...

Comment: It's still impossible for the second lookahead to ever match. And the anchor `^` was probably intended as a negation, so there's some confusion with character classes as well. The captures would also only capture one character (the last one of both the prefix and suffix). I think we can conclude this pattern is simply broken.

Comment: The code doesn't use any captured groups, and if it did it would need to capture the whole word, not individual letters as it does. I've concluded that he just wrote bad regex.